# Donor and acceptor concentrations on a Si speciment

Tags: semiconductor-physics

Suppose that we have a Si speciment and there are Ga atom impurities of $2*10^{16} \text{cm}^{-3} $. I was thinking, if we insert As atom impurities of $4*10^{16} \text{cm}^{-3}$ at the first half of the speciment, do the Ga atoms bond with the As atoms and have at the n-side $N_D=2*10^{16} \text{cm}^{-3}$, or the As atoms do not interact with the Ga atoms and thus we have $N_D=4*10^{16}$ ?

[image]

Comment: One is a donor and one is an acceptor in silicon.

Comment: I know that As is a donor and Ga is an acceptor in silicon, but that is not what I am asking here.

Comment: So what happens when you have donors and acceptors in the same volume?